# How to produce php+html in haxe

Tags: haxe

I would like to product php code within HTML with heXa.  For example:

```
<?php
$temp = 'Hello';
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $temp?>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I write the above using haxe?  The haxe site shows you how to produce PHP code, but it doesn't mention how to produce PHP with HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haxe isn't a scripting language that can be called from within a html file in that way. You have to adapt a workflow where you prepare your html templates and your data as separate units and let the compiled application combine them according to your wishes.

Here's a quick example that should work in any Haxe server target language (php, neko, cpp). (Maybe also java and c# - not sure if the Template implementation is ready) :

```
package ;

import haxe.Template;
import neko.Lib;

class Main 
{
    static function main() 
    {
        var data = { greeting: 'Hello' };       
        var template = new Template('<html><body>::greeting::</body></html>');      

        var output = template.execute(data);
        Sys.print(output);      
    }   
}
```

There are a bunch of template engines for Haxe out there, for example the .NET Razor clone  [Erazor](https://github.com/ciscoheat/erazor)

Comment: Thank you.  Other than being a noob question, I do not know why I received the down votes. I wish those who down-voted left a message. That aside, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @rexposadas See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286331/run-php-client-side

Comment: @rexposadas I don't know either - I upvoted the question. It is a good to know when you are coming from PHP to Haxe that you need to use templates.