# Run PHP client side

Tags: php

Is it possible to launch a PHP script, client side, using an HTML web page?

If not, is there a way to embed the PHP into the HTML so it can run client side?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: There is most likely a way to do the thing that you actually want to do though, you should ask about that instead.

Comment: @ultranaut I disagree - I think it might be possible. Are you sure it isn't (theoretically) possible to write a PHP interpreter in JavaScript, and then use it to run PHP scripts on the client side?

Comment: maybe this would help: http://phpjs.org/ or this one: https://code.google.com/p/php-to-js/ .. since GWT i would like to see a php to javascript compiler too. You just code in one language, web programming is a pain with all the different syntax ... ;-)

Comment: [Disclaimer: I am the author] You could use Uniter to execute PHP client side - it is essentially a PHP interpreter written in JavaScript - http://asmblah.github.io/uniter/demo/interactive.html - Sorry, I would have added this as an answer if the question wasn't closed.

Comment: A long long long time ago, in the beginning of the php4 era, there was a Mozilla (pre-firefox, if memory serves) plugin for doing client side php code. It even supported <script language="php">. At the time, the way I thought of it, it was a welcome alternative to client side vbscript and a much needed alternative to js. Never really took off. It's long gone, and probably for the better.

Answer (score 9):

I think what you want is JavaScript. PHP is meant for server-side and JavaScript is meant for client side, among other things.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with javascript as it is with php?

Comment: Yes, like Daniil said. you can think of javascript like php for the client. (this is a very simplistic view, as Daniil pointed out there are many, many applications for javascript). try [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) for an introduction.

Comment: As of 2020, it's also possible to [compile PHP to WebAssembly](https://github.com/oraoto/pib) and run it in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

No. PHP cannot be run in browser. Learn JavaScript, alternatively [CoffeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) if you don't like JavaScript's syntax.

Comment: Writing desktop applications. PHP is probably not the very best language to create a desktop application with a graphical user interface, but if you know PHP very well, and would like to use some advanced PHP features in your client-side applications you can also use PHP-GTK to write such programs. You also have the ability to write cross-platform applications this way. PHP-GTK is an extension to PHP, not available in the main distribution. If you are interested in [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/), visit » its own website.

Comment: Have they been updating PHP-GTK? Last I looked, it was kind of a mess.

Comment: To run a PHP script in a browser, you would need to [compile it into JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995362/looking-for-transpiler-php-to-javascript) first.

Comment: https://atymic.dev/blog/client-side-php